# .htaccess not working with some PHP files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess` file that wont find some `php` files but will find others. Example,

> `RewriteRule ^test$ test.php`

will give a `404 not found` but

> `RewriteRule ^custom$ test.php`

will work.

Its the same for a rule that will add .php to the end of the URL. Any ideas?

Full file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test$ test.php #doesn't work
RewriteRule ^custom$ test.php #works
```

full directory(ls -a)

```
.  ..  .htaccess  index.html  test.php
```

Thanks.

Comment: What url are you entering in your browser for the first rule?

Comment: just [IPaddress]/test. like with the custom to test it works but test to test dosn't

Comment: please post your full htaccess including other rules

Comment: does fold `test` exist? does folder `custom` exits? I guess you'll find your answer there.

Comment: @PedroLobito test and custom aren't folders but like i said custom to test works but test to test doesn't.

Comment: so...post the real dirs or at least check if the dirs already exist on your system.

Comment: Those folders don't need to exist for .htaccess to redirect them

Comment: @ViperCode who said they need to exist? it would take all the purpose of using .htaccess. I just asked the OP to check if the dirs already exist, I'm sure his answer is there. The syntax is correct, the problem has to do with a dir or file that's already present on his system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `multiviews` is OFF so that it's not causing any funny business trying to match files. Also **always** use the `[L]` so that it stops processing rules when a rule is met. That can also cause issues down the line by continuing to run other rules. It should not matter if you have a trailing slash or not. For good measure you can check with conditions too so that if it's not a real file or not a real directory it will process the rule and you won't get a 404.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/?$ test.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^custom/?$ test.php [L]
```

Comment: Nice explanation, 1+.

Answer (score 1):

When there exist a file/folder in your root directory with rule name, it wont work as desired. Because entering `http://127.0.0.1/test` will change it to `http://127.0.0.1/test/` directory by default. but not with `http://127.0.0.1/custom` so add a trailing slash to your rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/$ test.php
RewriteRule ^custom$ test.php
```

Comment: "When there exist a file with rule name, it wont work as desired", or dir,  correct, 1+.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1.php [L,R=301]
```

This is what I use on my website to add trailing slashes, I modified it to add .php instead. Is this what you are looking for?

or this should work also

```
RewriteRule ^test test.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^custom test.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Which question are you answering? I guess not this one.

Comment: and why it should work ? what is it doing specifically?